# Cannot authenticate using libcloud GCE Driver

Tags: python, libcloud, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to use libcloud (1.3.0) to connect to my GCE project using the following code:

```
from libcloud.compute.types import Provider
from libcloud.compute.providers import get_driver

USER_ID = "nnnnnnnn@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com"
KEYFILE = "./xxxxxxx.json"
PROJECT = "project1"

cls = get_driver(Provider.GCE)
driver = cls(USER_ID, KEYFILE, project = PROJECT)
```

This just fails with an AttributeError inside PyCrypto (I'm running v2.6.1):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "g.py", line 9, in <module>
    driver = cls(USER_ID, KEYFILE, project = PROJECT)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libcloud/compute/drivers/gce.py", line 1348, in __init__
    super(GCENodeDriver, self).__init__(user_id, key, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libcloud/common/base.py", line 1179, in __init__
    self.connection = self.connectionCls(*args, **conn_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libcloud/compute/drivers/gce.py", line 98, in __init__
    credential_file=credential_file, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libcloud/common/google.py", line 765, in __init__
    user_id, key, auth_type, credential_file, scopes, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libcloud/common/google.py", line 660, in __init__
    self.token = self.oauth2_conn.get_new_token()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libcloud/common/google.py", line 530, in get_new_token
    signature = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(signer.sign(hash_func))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Crypto/Signature/PKCS1_v1_5.py", line 110, in sign
    em = EMSA_PKCS1_V1_5_ENCODE(mhash, k)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Crypto/Signature/PKCS1_v1_5.py", line 211, in EMSA_PKCS1_V1_5_ENCODE
    digestAlgo  = DerSequence([hash.oid, DerNull().encode()])
AttributeError: oid
```

I've followed all the instructions on the libcloud GCE driver page about setting up the service account, downloading the JSON file etc so I think I am doing the right steps but I can't get past this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested that on Python 2.7.12 with PyCrypto 2.6.1 and don't see any issues on libcloud 1.3.0. Looking at the hasher, I suspect it's an issue with your service account configuration.

```
from libcloud.compute.types import Provider
from libcloud.compute.providers import get_driver

USER_ID = "559xxxxxx-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
KEYFILE = "./libcloud-test-xxx.json"
PROJECT = "libcloud-test"

cls = get_driver(Provider.GCE)
driver = cls(USER_ID, KEYFILE, project = PROJECT)
print(driver.auth_type)  # should be SA
print(driver.list_nodes())
```

From API Manager, I went to Credentials, then selected "Create Credentials" - > "Service Account Key".
For Service Account I selected "Compute Engine default service account" and the JSON format.

Compute Engine default service account

[image]

Within the credential manager the service account looks like this

[image]